# custom post type grid with content in lightbox

Tags: posts, the-content, lightbox

I'm going around every single wordpress plugin and impossible to find something with this featured . . . .

I need a grid list of some custom post type - with inline filter.

This is fine and tons of plugin can do this, such as essential grid.

Otherwise, on click, I need to display the_content on a lightbox, and I can not find anything with this featured.... They all display post on a new page - or just display the thumbnail - sometime the_title in the lightbox . . . .

Any plugin or possibilities to achieve this than somebody know ?

It will be fantastic :)

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the "Responsive Lightbox" plugin and use the "Inline" option.  For more info, visit [the plugin homepage](https://weaveapps.com/shop/wordpress-plugins/responsive-lightbox-lite/)
and scroll down to the "Sample Code" section.  First sample is "inline contents".  I've used this to build a portfolio from a custom post type.  It's simple and works well so far.